# Proving that no tile can fill both squares and equilateral triangles

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles, rectangles, tessellations

Cut up a square into a finite number of identical tiles.

Here is one possibility:

[image: square with 4 tiles]

How do I prove that the tiles could never be rearranged to form an equilateral triangle (with filled interior and no overlapping tiles)?  This is easy to see for the cut drawn above (though I intentionally chose 60 degree angles), but how do I prove it in general?

As for my attempts at proving this, I think this becomes a question of listing the ways that a square can be cut into equal pieces.  Instead of the cut drawn above, one could cut the square into "rational rectangles" and halve the rectangles into triangles, but all angles then must have rational tangents and therefore can never sum to a 60 degree angle.  Also, by equating the area of the square and the area of the equilateral triangle, we know that some tile edge lengths must irrationally divide the square edge length.  Beyond these two conclusions, I am stuck, but have a feeling that there is a very easy proof here which will leave me feeling foolish.

To be clear, all tiles must be used in the rearrangement and no tiles can be flipped over, but I think I could relax these two conditions also and still never form an equilateral triangle.

Comment: All polygons with the same area are scissor-congruent, so it can be done. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallace%E2%80%93Bolyai%E2%80%93Gerwien_theorem. Oops, EDIT: Sorry, I missed the word 'identical', so ignore this comment.

Comment: Is allowed to cut/reassemble so that the tile's angle touches the side of another tile ?

Comment: @Bongo Yes, you just need to make a triangle with no gaps and no overlaps. Many tiles touching at a corner, or two tiles touching along a full edge, is fine

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment:

In a simple case, suppose the areas of square is equal to area of triangle. As can be seen in figures a and b we can tile isosceles triangles as an square with equal area , provided the side angles are a multiple of $15^o$.

[image]

In figure c the area of equilateral triangle Q'UV is equal to area of rectangle $RR'_1S'_1D_1$. Now we have to construct an square equal in area with this rectangle. But this is impossible because the product of two unequal integers can not be equal to square of an integer.

Comment: What about the infinitely-many other ways to cut the square?  I was really hoping a proof wouldn't require listing all the ways, but as time goes on with no answer, now thinking there is no easy way to prove this.

Comment: "the product of two unequal integers can not be equal to square of an integer." Really? What about 1*4=4 or 2*18=4*9=36?